# The usage of 大規模

Tags: word-choice

Which option is sound more natural (colloquial):

> 政府が法律をしたい変更に反対して、大きなデモが行われました。1万人以上が参加しました。

> 政府が法律をしたい変更に反対して、大規模なデモが行われました。1万人以上が参加しました。

I have the impression that 大規模 is a bit too much in that context and maybe a bit too formal.
If there is anything else you would change in the sentence, please tell me (I want to be able to notice my mistakes).

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by 法律をしたい変更?

Comment: Ａ change in a law that the government want to do. I tried a lot of word order in this sentence and couldn't make it correct apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall tone of these sentences *does* look like a formal news article, so this 大規模 doesn't look unnatural or overly formal at all. 大きな is not bad, but it sounds a bit too elementary. (But are you actually trying to make casual sentences like those spoken among friends? Then you need to change not just 大規模 but almost everywhere.)

And 政府が法律をしたい only means something nonsense like "the government wants to do law". You need to say 政府が行いたい法律の変更 instead.

Comment: Thanks! So how would you rephrase it to sound less formal and more natural?

Comment: @AsafAyalon "例の法律変更反対で1万人くらいのデカいデモやってるって" or something?

Comment: Thank a lot! Just one last question, what is the usage of 例 in this context? I know it means "example" but is there another translation that I don't know?

Comment: @AsafAyalon https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BE%8B%E3%81%AE